# Subclassing UICollectionView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

Does anybody know how to subclass a `UICollectionView` in Xamarin.iOS?

I tried this

```
public class MyCustomUICollectionView : UICollectionView
{

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public InfinitiveScrollingUICollectionView (CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        // initialization
    }
}
```

but I get

> The best overloaded method match for `UIKit.UICollectionView.UICollection(Foundation.NSCoder) has some invalid arguments
>   Argument #1 cannot convert`CoreGraphics.CGRect`expression to type`Foundation.NSCoder`.

I also tried to use `public InfinitiveScrollingUICollectionView ()` but I get

> The type `UIKit.UICollectionView` does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

I want to override `LayoutSubviews`. Or should the `UICollectionViewController` be used for such a purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionView` has no constructor that accepts a single `CGRect`, so you have to pass a layout, too:

```
public class MyCustomUICollectionView : UICollectionView
{
    public MyCustomUICollectionView(CGRect frame, UICollectionViewLayout layout) 
        : base(frame, layout)
    {
    }
}
```

If you want to, you can also create the layout internally, so you don't have to pass it from the outside:

```
public class MyCustomUICollectionView : UICollectionView
{
    private static readonly UICollectionViewLayout _layout;

    static MyCustomUICollectionView()
    {
        // Just an example
        _layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
    }

    public MyCustomUICollectionView(CGRect frame) : base(frame, _layout)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know where I can look up the constructor? I tried to use the first approach you posted. I put this in the constructor of `UICollectionViewController`: `this.CollectionView = new MyCustomUICollectionView(this.View.Frame,layout)` but here he couldn't dequeue a cell. It does work in `ViewDidLoad` when I create a new layout. Shouldn't it work in the constructor also?

Comment: See http://blog.thomasbandt.de/39/2434/de/blog/monotouch-viewdidload-gets-called-before-constructor.html

Comment: When I instantiate my `UICollectionViewController` I have to pass a layout. Should I pass a fake layout or should I temporarily store the layout in a variable before I can pass it to `MyCustomUICollectionView`?

Comment: If you want to instantiate layout and collection view later on, just don't use an UICollectionViewController, instead use a normal UIViewController and add a new UICollectionView.

Comment: Ok. Who does get the method calls like `NumberOfSections`, `GetItemsCount` and `GetCell` then? Is it the collection view itself or do I have to define an `UICollectionViewDataSource`?

Comment: You add the collection view as subview and a `UICollectionViewSource` has to be defined (includes `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`).