# UIScrollView Xamarin Ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

How to use both vertical and horizontal ScrollView in Xamarin iOS ?

I am using `CollectionView` but with it I only get one `scrollview` working at a time.

Comment: [This post on Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20834/horizontal-scrollview-within-vertical-scrollview) seems to be wath you want.

Comment: Yes but I want to working vertical and horizontal scrollview IN Xamarin ios @Louis'LYRO'Dupont

Comment: You want a scrollView that can scroll in both vertical and horizontal ? Or a CollectionView that can scroll in both vertical and horizontal ??

Comment: Collectionview that can scroll in both vertical and horizontal in xamarin iOS @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Check the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179703/uicollectionview-scrolling-in-both-directions) thread may help.

Comment: Thanks but Not working can help for Xamarin iOS solution @JackHua-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's nature of collection view, you can make it scroll in one direction at a time i.e. either horizontal or vertical. What you exactly want to achieve that you have not mentioned. if you are going to use collection view inside the scroll view, you have to manage it properly.

> The best solution would be use a UICollectionView for the horizontal
>   scroll and the  UITableView for the vertical scroll.

But if you want to make it work only using UICollectionView you have to use Subclassing UICollectionViewLayout.

here is link you can refer to make it work, hope this might help you:

1.https://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

2.[Subclassing UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302301/subclassing-uicollectionview)

3.[UICollectionView scrolling in both directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179703/uicollectionview-scrolling-in-both-directions)